# Android HorizontalScrollView and Scrollview Vertical Not Working

Tags: android, xml, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

[image: Please check output Image It's show this output]

here is my xml code.

this code not working `HorizontalScrollView` i need `HorizontalScrollView` and vertical.
if i use `HorizontalScrollView` it's create width problem of my all view 
i have uploaded image screenshots. and in this layout i use multiple `Listview`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#f0ece1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Home_FR">



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LLMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="My Detail"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="#f0ece1">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/inplay_rectangle">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/ButtonInplay"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="33"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:background="#284252"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:text="Current Details"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="3dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/ButtonToday"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="34"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:text="Details History"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="3dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/ButtonTomorrow"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="33"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:text="@string/profitandloss"/>

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#e0e6e6">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Details Status"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:prompt="@string/spinner_title"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp">

        </Spinner>

    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#3b5160">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Unmatched"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#e0e6e6">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Market"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Selection Type"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="User ID"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Usr Placed"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Odds req."
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Matched"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Unmatched"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Date Matched"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/ListviewUnmatched"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                </ListView>
            </LinearLayout>



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="#3b5160">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="matched"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="#e0e6e6">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Market"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_weight="30"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Selection Type"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_weight="10"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="UI ID"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_weight="10"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="UONE Placed"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_weight="10"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Odds req."
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_weight="10"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/Matched"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_weight="10"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Avg. odds matched "
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_weight="10"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Date Matched"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_weight="10"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/ListviewMatched"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                </ListView>
            </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


    </HorizontalScrollView>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this line of code

Add This line in Horizontal scroll view to solve views width problem

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">
```

**android:fillViewport="true"**

I have add this line in horizontal scrollview

i hope it hepls you